# std::unique_ptr interfering with certain sf::RenderWindow functions?

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

`sf::RenderWindow::getPosition()` always returns `0, 0` instead of the correct position when I call it from the same scope in which the window is created.

Here's the example code that reproduces the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow> window_;

  window_ = std::unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow>(
    new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "asd", sf::Style::Default)
  );
  window_->setFramerateLimit(30);
  window_->setVerticalSyncEnabled(false);

  while (window_->isOpen()) {
    sf::Event evt;
    while (window_->pollEvent(evt)) {
      if (evt.type == sf::Event::Closed) { window_->close(); }
    }
    window_->clear();
    window_->display();
  }

  const sf::Vector2i wpos = window_->getPosition();
  std::cout << "window position: " << wpos.x << "/" << wpos.y <<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The thing is: I have for example a class `MainMenu` to which I pass a `sf::RenderWindow *` (with `window_.get()`).

When I call `window_->getPosition()` from `MainMenu` it reports the correct position, so `getPosition()` itself is not faulty. It's only wrong when I call it from within the same scope (in main).

I'm using SFML 2.3.1 by the way

Comment: You should construct the `unique_ptr` and initialize it at the same time: `unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow> window_(new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "asd", sf::Style::Default));`.

Comment: I know but this is just an example code. In my real game the `unique_ptr` is a class member variable and I construct the window later

Comment: BTW, there's no need to have a `new` `RenderWindow`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are printing the window position after a loop on `while (window_->isOpen())`.  This means the window is closed, i.e. it does not exist when you call `getPosition()`.  Therefore it is no surprise that the window position is not reported "correctly," because the window has already been closed (permanently, so it has no position).